# Cross-compiling python packages for arm64

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling

I'm stuck when compiling/linking python packages for an arm64 target. The compilation happens in a docker container, which is set up by this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt clean && apt -y update && apt -y install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu build-essential wget
RUN apt clean && apt -y update && apt -y install libssl-dev libffi-dev gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libgdbm-dev libdb5.3-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libsqlite3-dev tcl-dev tk tk-dev
```

Compilation works fine, however for some packages, e.g. scipy, the linker fails to link the required libraries:

```
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so when searching for -lopenblas
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.a when searching for -lopenblas
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so when searching for -lopenblas
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.a when searching for -lopenblas
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so when searching for -lm
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
  /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
```

Which is caused by not having the libraries as arm64 version available, but only as x86_64 which the linker can not use. What I'm failing at is getting the arm64 on the system.

After searching stackoverflow, I tried to simply install the required arm64 versions of the libraries by changing the Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt clean && apt -y update && apt -y install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu build-essential wget
RUN apt clean && apt -y update && apt -y install libssl-dev libffi-dev gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libgdbm-dev libdb5.3-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libsqlite3-dev tcl-dev tk tk-dev

RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64

RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com focal main"
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com focal universe"
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com focal restricted"

RUN apt clean && apt update && apt -y install libblas3:arm64 liblapack3:arm64
```

However, this resulted in

```
libblas3:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
liblapack3:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.29) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc-s1:arm64 (>= 4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgfortran5:arm64 (>= 8) but it is not going to be installed
```

When I manually add the dependencies, I get errors that the arm64 versions are breaking the amd64 versions, and vice versa.

The last option I see is getting the source and compiling it myself. However that seems unneccessary, as the libraries are available, I just can't get them installed. Can somebody show me what I missed along the way?

Comment: I think that if you set up your docker build environment for arm64, it will run the build within QEMU and during the build process your intermediate containers will understand naturally what architecture they have, making your image much more portable and making problems of this nature go away. Are you trying to do things following suggestions such as in this tutorial? https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds/